# Does Agoge count toward naval units as well?

Tags: civilization-6

Or is it just land units? There are melee and ranged units for both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Agoge](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Agoge_(Civ6)) states: +50% Production Production toward Ancient and Classical era melee and ranged units.

This doesn't include naval units from the era.

If you wanted a bonus for naval units in the era you would want [Maritime Industries](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Maritime_Industries_(Civ6)) which provides +100% Production Production toward Ancient and Classical era naval units.